# How to Add Fonts to PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, regedit

Requirements:

- I want to use PowerShell, not alternate console applications. I'm aware that I can work around the issue by just using a different console application.
- I don't want to change my system locale. I'm aware doing this will work around my issue.

Background:
I'm using Japanese locale for non-Unicode programs, for compatibility with old software that I'm testing that uses Shift-JIS.

In the Shift-JIS code page, the code for backslash was used for a yen symbol. As a result, Japanese fonts display backslash as a Yen symbol instead.

[image: PowerShellYenPathSeparator]

When in Japanese locale, PowerShell defaults to only have five fonts, which are all Japanese, causing path separators to look like Yen symbols.

I want path separators to not look like Yen symbols, but like backslashes, from within PowerShell, while working with Japanese locale. (note: a similar issue happens with Korean locale and the won symbol)

I would like to add more fonts to PowerShell. How do I do this?
I searched and found other answers that suggest `regedit` to edit the registry and add the fonts I want, which sounded like it should work, but they didn't work for me.

The closest one I could find is:

`regedit.exe`

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`

add

000... whatever amount of zeros I need
with the name of the font as value

However, when I go to check
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`

It has four font values there, whereas in PowerShell [Font] tab I have five options, and those four values don't perfectly match those five options.

[image: PowerShellScreenshot]

[image: RegEditScreenshot]

How can I add a font of my choice, for example "Courier", to my PowerShell font selection menu in its Font tab in properties?

Comment: (1) Try in registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` to set your desired font-name in item `FaceName`. The current value `__DefaultTTFont__` lets the system choose a font depending on the code page. I don't know if this works for PowerShell or only for CMD. (2) You might also try PowerShell ISE.

Comment: As @harrymc states, PowerShellISE, under *Tools ->Options*, allows specifying fonts and styles for each pane.